# roslaunch and command OS

Tags: ros, roslauch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

can you include operating system commands as superuser in a launch file?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/273023/roslaunch-and-command-os/) by [mag.rod](https://answers.ros.org/users/30299/mag.rod/) on ROS Answers with karma: 58 on 2017-10-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> can you include operating system commands [..] in a launch file?

Please see #q272267.

> as superuser

yes, see #q165246 for instance. But, also see #q189457, as it's rarely really needed to run things as `root`. In almost all cases it can be solved with configuring the proper permissions for the user starting the ROS node.

Try to avoid it.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-10-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0